# Rails 4 `rake db:migrate` in Heroku instances, references error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, migrate, pg

I'm trying to `rake db:migrate` my project in **Heroku's servers** but the `rake` process is trying to create an table `targetings` before `ads` where `targetings` has a relation with `ads` so the references error pops up, like:

> ```
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "ads" does not exist
> : ALTER TABLE "targetings" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_dcece48daa"
> FOREIGN KEY ("ad_id")
>   REFERENCES "ads" ("id")
> ```

Can some one tell me how define an order or force the table `ads` being created **before** the others?

Comment: you are trying to add ad_id ref on targetings  relation but ad relation is not exist there

Comment: yes! can you tell me how to make it right? @uzaif

Comment: did you change manually  in migration file?

Comment: I don't think so... I can do it locally... but when I try this in a heroku server... breaks! @uzaif

Comment: did you setup database on heroku?

Comment: heroku run rake db:setup

Comment: @uzaif please answer this! It worked!!! THANKS, in the herokus page... it does not talk about the setup thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In heroku production environment
First you have to set up database with this command

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

Comment: Thanks! it really helped!